# Stripping out numerical array keys from var_export

Tags: php, arrays

I want to do [var_export()](http://php.net/var_export) and strip out all numerical array keys on an array.  My array outputs like so:

```
array (
  2 => 
  array (
    1 => 
    array (
      'infor' => 'Radiation therapy & chemo subhead',
      'PPOWithNotif' => '',
      'PPOWithOutNotif' => 'Radiation therapy & chemo PPO amount',
      'NonPPO' => 'Radiation therapy & chemo Non PPO amount',
    ),
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    1 => 
    array (
      'infor' => 'Allergy testing & treatment subhead',
      'PPOWithNotif' => '',
      'PPOWithOutNotif' => 'Allergy testing & treatment PPO amount',
      'NonPPO' => 'Allergy testing & treatment Non PPO amount',
    ),
  )
)
```

By doing this I can shuffle the array values however needed without having to worry about numerical array values.

I've tried using `echo preg_replace("/[0-9]+ \=\>/i", '', var_export($data));` but it doesn't do anything.  Any suggestions?  Is there something I'm not doing with my regex?  Is there a better solution for this altogether?

Comment: can you be more clear about what it is you are trying to ultimately do? Like, a before and after of the array, or what you want out of it? Because if you take var_export() as a string representation of the array, it's no longer an array that you can shuffle

Comment: I want to remove the numerical array keys from this string...

Comment: right..I get that, but then you talk about shuffling array values.  If you use var_export to turn the array into a string, it's no longer an array and you can't shuffle it at all, because it's no longer an array, it's a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the second parameter of `var_export` to `true`, or else there is no return value given to your `preg_replace` call.

---

Reference: https://php.net/manual/function.var-export.php

> **return**
>   If used and set to **TRUE**, **var_export()** will return the variable
>   representation instead of outputting it.

---

*Update:* Looking back on this question, I have a hunch, a simple `array_values($input)` would have been enough.

Comment: An example could be: <?php $export = preg_replace('(\d+\s=>)', "", var_export($arr, true));

Comment: array_values would reindex the array, when I think the goal is just to avoid `var_export` adding the explicit numerical index.

Comment: The risk of using `preg_replace()` (or any string manipulation) is that it risks over matching.  If any of the values (not keys followed by an arrow) contain qualifying text, they will be replaced as well.  All researchers need to be aware that this vulnerability should be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the answer you are looking for, but if you have a **one level array**, you can use the function below. It may not be beautiful, but it worked well for me.

```
function arrayToText($array, $name = 'new_array') {
  $out = '';
  foreach($array as $item) {
    $export = var_export($item, true);
    $export = str_replace("array (\n", '', $export);
    $export = substr($export, 0, -1);
    $out .= "[\n";
    $out .= $export;
    $out .= "],\n";
  }
  return '$' . $name . ' = ' . "[\n" . substr($out, 0, -2) . "\n];";
}

echo arrayToText($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

This package does the tricks
https://github.com/brick/varexporter

```
use Brick\VarExporter\VarExporter;
echo VarExporter::export([1, 2, ['foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => []]]);
```

Output:

```
[
    1,
    2,
    [
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'baz' => []
    ]
]
```

Comment: Does this remove _all_ numeric keys?  or does it only remove indexes?  Your sample removes indexes, while the OP's sample keys are numeric but not indexes.  This is just an ambiguity that is worth clarifying.

Comment: Here have 2 things,  var_export always gives you the output with numeric keys and which is resolved by that package. But when you shuffle, then keys are changed and either `var_export` or this package is able to remove that because keys are not in order. So, after suffle have to reset the keys to get the output without numeric keys.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying that it removes indexes, but not int-type associative keys.  Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score -3):

Why not just use [`array_rand`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php):

```
 $keys = array_rand($array, 1);
 var_dump($array[$keys[0]]); // should print the random item
```

PHP also has a function, [`shuffle`](http://php.net/shuffle), which will shuffle the array for you, then using a `foreach` loop or the `next` / `each` methods you can pull it out in the random order.